# Displaying button using jquery when two values are equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to pass the parameter from function calculateSumc1 to calculateSumc2. And when both the values of sum and sum1 are equal it should display the show button. Even if the sum is equal , the save button is not being displayed.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save" style="display:none" value="Save" />


$(".c1").click(function ()
    {
        $(this).keyup(function ()
        {
            calculateSumc1();
        });
    });
$(".c2").click(function ()
{
    $(this).keyup(function ()
    {
        calculateSumc2();
    });
});

function calculateSumc1()
{
    var sum = 0;
    $(".c1").each(function ()
    {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0)
        {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#debit").html(sum);
    //calculatetotal(sum);
    calculateSumc2(sum);
}

function calculateSumc2(sum)
{
    var sum1 = 0;
    $(".c2").each(function ()
    {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0)
        {
            sum1 += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#credit").html(sum1);
    console.log("sum1" + sum1);
    while (sum == sum1)
    {
        $("#save").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: how many times you can click that $(".c1"),,$(".c2 ") button ..it will binded key up event every time

Comment: did not get it at all, but shouldn't it be  *if (sum == sum1)* instead of  *while (sum == sum1)*

Comment: it was if , but i changed it into while just to see if it works. It doesnt work for both

Comment: Yes , it a keyup event. it can make n no of entries. but towards the end the valu of sum and sum1 shud be equal when it is , the save button shud be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one event handler for all the elements, sum everything up and compare in that event handler

```
$('.c1, .c2').on('keyup', function() {

    var sum1 = $.map( $('.c1'), function(x) {
        return +x.value;
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });

    var sum2 = $.map( $('.c2'), function(x) {
        return +x.value;
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });

    $("#debit").html(sum1);
    $("#credit").html(sum2);

    $("#save").toggle( sum1 === sum2 );

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cj4A9/)